# Content-Security-Policy not working in Firefox

Tags: security, firefox, content-security-policy

We are adding a Content Security Policy on our websites to prevent outside sources from using IFrames other than our own.

We are using .NET and have the following in our web.config to do this.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' http://*.ourwebsite1.com http://*.ourwebsite2.com http://*.ourwebsite3.com https://*.ourwebsite1.com https://*.ourwebsite2.com https://*.ourwebsite3.com" />
```

It works fine in IE and Chrome, but in Firefox (latest version), we are getting an error saying it was blocked by Content Security Policy. I know it is only supported on Firefox 23+, but we are all using latest version.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message in the console?

Comment: What is CSP header in devtools/firebug?